# How to get meta tag value with BeautifulSoup soup.select

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract date from one html tag. I'm using Python and Beautiful Soup.

```
<meta name="Email" content="info@info.de">
<meta name="Date" content="2021-04-28T20:35:00+02:00">
<meta name="title" content="Tris is tite">
```

I want to extract only date, so this should be result: `2021-04-28T20:35:00+02:00`

I know that I can do it like this:

```
tag = "meta['Date']"
date = soup.select(tag)
date = date['content']
```

But is is possible to do that only with one css selector, only with tag value?
For example, something like this?

```
tag = "meta['Date']['content']" # or something like this?
date = soup.select(tag)
print(date)
2021-04-28T20:35:00+02:00
```

PS
I have to use `soup.select`, `soup.find(...)` and `soup.select_one` does not work for me.
So only `soup.select` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. It seems you are confusing the attribute names. Try:

```
tag = "meta[content]" 
date = soup.select_one(tag)
print(date.get('content'))
```

Output:

```
2021-04-28T20:35:00+02:00
```

Edit:
Change the tag line to:

```
tag = "meta[content][name='Date']"
```

Comment: I have updated my question, maybe I should point out earlier that there are a lot of meta tags, and that I just want Date tag

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> content = """<meta name="Date" content="2021-04-28T20:35:00+02:00"> """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find("meta", {"name": "Date"}).attrs['content']
>>> '2021-04-28T20:35:00+02:00'
```

If you want to extract all 'meta' tags and display the Date properties using 'select':

```
>>> for item in soup.select("meta"):
...     print(item.attrs.get('content'))
```

Comment: I have to use soup.select, soup.find(...) and soup.select_one does not work for me. So only soup.select works
Im looking for solution with soup.select